# Run a Nant script in fire and forget fashion from CruiseControl.net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

How can I write a Nant or Exec task (which calls the nant.exe) in a fire and forget manner - in Cruise Control .NET.  I do not want CruiseControl to wait for the Nant script to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this is not what cruise control is designed to do. Ideally it would capture the output and store this in the build log.

However if you want to invoke a process and not wait for it to exit you would need to invoke a process that will then start your nant instance and exit immediately.

You could achieve this by using a carefully crafted call to cmd, e.g.

```
cmd.exe /c "start '' /b nant.exe <target> -Dparam=value"
```

This should work although I've not tried it.

Comment: Yes I will be soon testing the solution you have provided.